# Place Order button is not working in one page checkout page magento

Tags: jquery, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.0.1
I used lotusbreath one page checkout extension ver. 3.2.1 but when i selected guest user, After completing all steps when i clicked on Place Order button, ajax for post is calling but it is not going to success page and showing error `ReferenceError: Review is not defined` but It is working fine for registered user.

Please see the code below:

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/lotusbreath/onestepcheckout/onepage/review/info.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('items_before'); ?>

<div id="checkout-review-table-wrapper">
    <table class="table data-table" id="checkout-review-table">
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): $colspan = $rowspan = 2; else: $colspan = $rowspan = 1; endif; ?>

        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan ?>"><?php echo $this->__('PHOTO') ?></th>
           <?php /*?> <th colspan="<?php echo $colspan ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th><?php */?>
            <th colspan="<?php echo $colspan ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Size') ?></th>
            <th rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan ?>" wrap="wrap" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <th colspan="<?php echo $colspan ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
            <!--<th colspan="<?php echo $colspan ?>" class="a-center remove-item-diplay" style="display: none;"></th> -->
        </tr>
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                <!--<th></th> -->
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </thead>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>

        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('items_after'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">//jQuery('#checkout-review-table').decorate('table');</script>
<div id="checkout-review-submit">

</div>
<div id="checkout-paypaliframe-load" class="authentication white-popup mfp-hide"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    review = new Review();
    //]]>
</script>
```

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/lotusbreath/onestepcheckout/onepage/review/totals.phtml

```
<?php
$isNewsletter = Mage::getStoreConfig('lotusbreath_onestepcheckout/general/allowsubscribe');
if ($isNewsletter){
    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail(
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail());
        if($subscriber && $subscriber->getId())
        {
            $isNewsletter = false;
        }

    }
}
?>
<?php if ($this->getTotals()): ?>
<tfoot>

    <?php $_colspan = $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 5 : 3; ?>
    <?php echo $this->renderTotals(null, $_colspan); ?>
    <!--<tr>
        <td class="a-right" colspan="4" style="height: 10px;"></td>
    </tr>
    !-->
    <?php echo $this->renderTotals('footer', $_colspan); ?>

    <?php if ($this->needDisplayBaseGrandtotal()):?>
    <tr>

        <td class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $_colspan; ?>">
            <small><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Your credit card will be charged for') ?></small>
        </td>
        <td class="a-right">
            <small><?php echo $this->displayBaseGrandtotal() ?></small>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif?>

    <tr>
        <td class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $_colspan+ 1;?>">

            <div class="row edit-cart-review">

            <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('lotusbreath_onestepcheckout/revieworder/show_link_cart')):?>
                <div class="forgot-link">
                    <span> <?php echo $this->__('Forgot an Item?') ?> <a
                            href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Edit Your Cart') ?>
                        </a>
                    </span>

                </div>
            <?php endif;?>

                <?php
                $canEditCart = Mage::getStoreConfig('lotusbreath_onestepcheckout/revieworder/can_edit_cart');
                ?>
                <?php if ($canEditCart):?>
                    <div class="lt-buttons-set right" id="review-buttons-container">
                        <button type="button" name="edit_cart_action" id="edit_cart_action"
                                value="update_qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('Edit Your Cart') ?>" class="button btn-update">
                            <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Edit Your Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                        <button type="button" name="edit_cart_action" id="update_cart_action"
                                value="update_qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update') ?>" class="button btn-update" style="display: none;">
                            <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update') ?></span></span></button>
                        <button type="button" name="edit_cart_action" id="cancel_cart_action"
                                value="update_qty" title="<?php echo $this->__('Cancel') ?>" class="button btn-close" style="display: none;"m>
                            <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Cancel') ?></span></span></button>
                    </div>

                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
            <?php if ($isNewsletter):?>
                <p class="newsletter">

                    <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter-signup" name="newsletter" value="1"
                           title="<?php echo Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>"
                           class="checkbox"
                        <?php
                        echo Mage::getStoreConfig('lotusbreath_onestepcheckout/general/autochecksubscriber') ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                        ?>
                        />
                    <label for="newsletter-signup">
                        <?php echo Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>
                    </label>
                </p>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('agreements') ?>
            <div id="saveOder-error" class="error"></div>
            <button role='review-save' type="submit"
                    title="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Place Order') ?>" name="submitbtn"
                    id="lbonepage-place-order-btn" class="button btn-checkout">
                <span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Place Order') ?></span></span>
            </button>

        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If anyboby knows it, please help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: If that really is the way review is being initialized, it's missing some data in its constructor. Take a look at the default template (base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phml).
Also, are the correct javascript files included in the page?

Comment: No, I tried but it didn't work

Comment: can anyone please help me to get the solution

Answer (score 0):

Change the script in lotusbreath/onestepcheckout/onepage/review/info.phtml to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: I already tried it but the problem is not solved in JSON it shows success false error true why i don't know

Comment: There is no any page in var/report folder but in response section it shows in result array: error_messages":"Please check shipping address information. Please enter the telephone number."

Comment: Telephone number is mandatory on checkout page you have to put validation on client side which is default in magento this error occur because telephone number is required and it also validate on server side which through error .can you provide me the link of the site

Comment: sorry actually the site is in local server so i can't provide you the link of site....yes i already put validation in telephone no and it is working fine as well but when i clicked on place order button response data will show this error

Answer (score 0):

Add the Script in the below file.

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
//]]>
```

Found the Fix in the below link.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305421/magento-ee-1-14-4-4-upgrade-console-error-on-place-order-in-ie

https://github.com/EBSCOSoftwareDev/siegeldisplay/commit/baa87eb796491b21e719f5e30f594c50131d45f2